# How to re-insert all old rows when month and year changed

Tags: sql-server

my table like........

```
 id  Sname  attendence    ADate  
  1   xyz        p          01/01/2013  mm/dd/yyyy
  2   zxc        A          01/01/2013
  3   asd        p          01/01/2013
```

Now if month changes then these rows auto-insert on page load event like

```
 id  Sname  attendence      ADate  
  1   xyz        p          01/01/2013   mm/dd/yyyy
  2   zxc        A          01/01/2013
  3   asd        p          01/01/2013
  1   xyz        p          02/01/2013
  2   zxc        A          02/01/2013   mm/dd/yyyy
  3   asd        p          02/01/2013
```

Previously I used only month 1, 2, 3,4 for this but problem with this is while it comes to 12 I have to insert 1 so it will affect old row. Please tell me what to do

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Use `cron jobs`

For this you can create a page which runs automatically on first date of month.

Comment: i am using it in windows applcation

Comment: It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348863/how-to-run-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-every-hour

Comment: Another example `Hourly cronjob on Windows` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192580/hourly-cronjob-on-windows